# sql union duplication problems with multiple AS statements

Tags: php, sql, union

Using the following sql query:

```
  SELECT id, title, description, publisher,
         city, state, date,
         MATCH (title, description, publisher) AGAINST ('pizza+view' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
    FROM job 
  HAVING score > 0.01 
  UNION 
  SELECT id, title, description, publisher,
         city, state, date, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('37') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('-122') ) + sin( radians('37') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
    FROM job
  HAVING distance < '175'
ORDER BY distance DESC
   LIMIT 0, 30
```

Results come back as:

```
id  title   description publisher   city    state   date    distance
```

score is being sent back as distance, thus no unique rows.

how can I change this up?

Comment: `UNION` requires the number of columns to be the same in all the queries being UNIONed, and that the data types match at each position.

Comment: The names of the result columns will be taken from the first SELECT in the UNION; _primus inter pares_ works here too.  Maybe you meant to do some sort of join instead of the union?  At least, if you want the score for some rows and the distance for others, you have some thinking to about how to phrase the query.  It might be that you do the UNION as a sub-query just to identify the interesting jobs, and then for each interesting job, you calculate (afresh?) the distance and score in a final result query.

Comment: Consider adding a default value for `distance` in the first UNION's table expression and a default value for `score` in the second.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: ...and because they omitted the `CORRESPONDING` keyword (presumably their SQL product doesn't support it) it does not attempt to match by attribute name.

Answer (score 1):

I would use subquery and order result by score and distance field so rows with same score will be sorted by distance. I've dropped score column from final result set, I wasn't sure whether you would need it in this case.

```
select id, title, description, publisher, city, state, date from (
    SELECT 
        id, title, description, publisher, city, state, date,
        MATCH (title, description, publisher) AGAINST ('pizza+view' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score,
        (3959 * acos( cos( radians('37') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('-122') ) + sin( radians('37') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
    FROM job 
) t
where score > 0.01 or distance < 175
order by score desc, distance desc
limit 0, 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CTE for the first statement.
Something like this:

```
WITH score as (  SELECT id, title, description, publisher, 
     city, state, date, 
     MATCH (title, description, publisher) AGAINST ('pizza+view' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score  
FROM job  
HAVING score > 0.01 )

SELECT j.id, j.title, j.description, j.publisher, 
     j.city, j.state, j.date, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('37') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) )   
     *        cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('-122') ) + sin( radians('37') ) * sin(   
radians  ( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance, s.score
FROM job j
LEFT OUTER JOIN score s ON s.ID = j.ID
HAVING j.distance < '175' 
ORDER BY distance DESC 
LIMIT 0, 30
```